# Why doesn't this function return a negative number?

Tags: python, function, return-value

I have this function here:

```
def g(x: int) -> int:
    if x > 0:
        x = x * (-1)
    if x < 0:
        x = x * (-1)
    return x
```

When I call the function for g(10), it returns 10. Why doesn't it return -10? What can I do to make it return -10?

Comment: Replace the second `if` with `elif`. Or remove the condition altogether since you do the same operation in both cases

Comment: It's also possible to directly return from inside the `if` to prevent operation from continuing when one succeeds. Raising an Exception at the end of the flow (the case where no `if` returned) may help find errors

Comment: @UnholySheep Thanks, that does fix it. Though, wouldn't the value of x have been set by the first if statement regardless? Why does adding elif fix the problem? Edit: Nevermind, I see why now. Thanks!

Comment: Whole function could be `return -x` (as long as you're only calling it with ints).

Comment: The second `if` gets checked after the first one is executed, including the first multiplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You checked twice, and therefore you negative the value twice, simple solution:

```
def g(x: int) -> int:
    if x > 0:
        x = x * (-1)
    elif x < 0:
        x = x * (-1)
    return x
    
print(g(10))
```

output:

```
-10
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is too complex, since the operation is the same under both if conditions- you could simplify it :

```
def g(x: int) -> int:
    return x * (-1)
```

But as for why your original code didn't work -

Imagine your value passed in is 10.

So the first if condition `if x > 0` is met and x now becomes -10 (`x=x * -1`)

The 2nd if condition is then tested `if x < 0` - and that is also now True, so x is changed back to 10.

Those two if statements are independent of each other, and they run in the order you give them, one after the other.

If you want them to be dependent then use elif :

```
def g(x: int) -> int:
    if x > 0:
        x = x * (-1)
    elif x < 0:
        x = x * (-1)
    return x
```

That would have acheived the result you wanted - but as mentioned at the top of this answer is simply too complicated for what you were actually trying to do.